# Git file deduplication with separate initialization

Tags: git

Suppose there exist two git repos, `repoA` and `repoB`.

These repos were initialized (`git init`) separately but contain the same files (as in binary data, i.e. someone `cp`'d the files manually).

Naturally, the entire commit chain for each repo is completely independent and share no common ancestor.

Suppose that they're pushed to a remote as separate branches (i.e. `git push remoteName master:repoX`), will the files be deduplicated in the way that they are stored by git?

Comment: Yes, they will be deduplicated. Git's object store (in the directory ".git/objects") can only contain one copy of each file hash.

Comment: However, note that during a push operation, the data might not be deduplicated over the network. In other words, host A might be sending an object to host B which host B already has. Host B will receive the object, notice that it is in the store already, and discard the new data.

Comment: @NayukiMinase: Please add those comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To quote https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#How_to_share_objects_between_existing_repositories.3F:

> ### How to share objects between existing repositories?
>
> Do
>
> ```
> echo "/source/git/project/.git/objects/" > .git/objects/info/alternates
> ```
>
> and then follow it up with
>
> ```
> git repack -a -d -l
> ```
>
> where the `-l` means that it will only put ''local'' objects in the
>   pack-file (strictly speaking, it will put any loose objects from the
>   alternate tree too, so you'll have a fully packed archive, but it
>   won't duplicate objects that are already packed in the alternate
>   tree).